# Best practice for secure data fetching with Mongodb Atlas

Tags: mongodb, security, mongodb-atlas

I have a client-side react app that I need to fetch information from a MongoDB Atlas collection that is being populated directly to the source by another individual. When I went to check out the connection string I noticed that the user password for db access would need to be present in the code:

(Not enough rep to  post images sorry)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGPPg.png

Now obviously if I include this right in my front-end code anybody will be able to see my password and that's no good. But I need this app to be self-contained and I don't want to have to host a server just to reroute the single  Get request that is called upon loading the site.

If I create a new user with read-only privileges, is it safe to keep that user's (super generic obviously) password in the front-end code for access to the db? Is there any harm in this? Am I correct in assuming that non-whitelisted IP addresses aren't  able to make requests to the Atlas db? The only  address that is going to be whitelisted is the IP where the web-app will be hosted, so I'd imagine I don't need to worry about someone spamming requests to rack up charges on my Atlas account or doing anything else malicious?

I'm a recent grad so I don't have much experience with secure deployment but I'm hoping I can change that this summer.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about "best" practices, but I'll try to answer according to what I would do:

> is it safe to keep that user's (super generic obviously) password in the front-end code for access to the db?

Yes you can create a read-only user. It's generally not a good idea to use a super-user to do your reads. I would only give as much access as the job requires.

> Am I correct in assuming that non-whitelisted IP addresses aren't able to make requests to the Atlas db?

Correct. Only whitelisted IPs will be able to connect to the Atlas instance.

Having answered that, I personally would either:

- create an API layer on top of the database to prevent direct access to the database by a client application, or
- (If applicable) create a [Stitch Webhook](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/services/create-a-service-webhook/) that provides a Stitch-based REST API layer on top of the Atlas deployment.

The idea is to provide security by limiting access to the database from the outside world. Using a whitelist is one layer of security. Using a REST API is further security layer that essentially forces anything that needs database access to go through a guarded gate that is under your control.

Some additional benefits of a REST API gateway:

- Should your Atlas URI changes in the future, you don't need to redeploy the client applications everywhere again. You just reconfigure the REST API gateway to point to the new Atlas URI, while your client application can still use the existing REST API address with no change.
- Limiting client connections to the database itself. Since only your API gateway can connect directly to the database, there is little chance that the database can get accidentally DDOSed when you have a lot of clients active at the same time.

Note that I would not consider the above to be "best" practice by any means. It's just how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks. Webhooks may be what I'm looking for with this one